# JPA/Hibernate: ManyToMany delete relation on Join Table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

**Disclaimer:** This is my first Java project; learning as I go.

**Background:** I've inherited a legacy database on which to build a new RESTful API. We're using [Elide](http://elide.io) with Spring Boot to provide a [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) compliant service.

**Reference:** [Example source code](https://gitlab.com/nerdstep/elide-test)

**Problem:** We have entities with a many-to-many relationship to each other and themselves by way of a join table. Consider the followig schema:

```
CREATE TABLE ALPHA (
  ID VARCHAR(255),
  NAME VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT PK_ALPHA PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE BRAVO (
  ID VARCHAR(255),
  NAME VARCHAR(255),
  CONSTRAINT PK_BRAVO PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE RELATIONSHIP (
  ID INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
  FROM_ID VARCHAR(255),
  TO_ID VARCHAR(255)
);
```

Where the resource entities are modeled as follows:

```
public class Alpha implements Serializable {

    private String id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Alpha> alphas = new HashSet<>();
    private Set<Bravo> bravos = new HashSet<>();

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid", strategy = "uuid")
    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "RELATIONSHIP",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FROM_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TO_ID")
    )
    public Set<Alpha> getAlphas() {
        return alphas;
    }

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "RELATIONSHIP",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "FROM_ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TO_ID")
    )
    public Set<Bravo> getBravos() {
        return bravos;
    }

}
```

And the relationship table:

```
public class Relationship implements Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private String fromId;
    private String toId;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FROM_ID")
    public String getFromId() {
        return fromId;
    }

    @Column(name = "TO_ID")
    public String getToId() {
        return toId;
    }

}
```

Now let's say we have an `Alpha` record `A1` with relationships to `A2`, `A3`, `B1`, and `B2`. First we delete the relationship to `A2`.

From our API this would be a `DELETE` request to `http://localhost:9000/api/alphas/a1/relationships/alphas` with BODY

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "type": "alphas", 
      "id": "a2" 
    }
  ]
}
```

Behind the scenes Hibernates does what I'm expecting and generates the following SQL queries:

```
2018-07-13 09:48:23.687 DEBUG 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
Hibernate: 
    select
        alpha0_.id as id1_0_,
        alpha0_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        alpha alpha0_ 
    where
        alpha0_.id in (
            ?
        )
2018-07-13 09:48:23.688 TRACE 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [a1]
2018-07-13 09:48:23.690 DEBUG 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
Hibernate: 
    select
        alphas0_.from_id as from_id2_2_0_,
        alphas0_.to_id as to_id3_2_0_,
        alpha1_.id as id1_0_1_,
        alpha1_.name as name2_0_1_ 
    from
        relationship alphas0_ 
    inner join
        alpha alpha1_ 
            on alphas0_.to_id=alpha1_.id 
    where
        alphas0_.from_id=?
2018-07-13 09:48:23.690 TRACE 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [a1]
2018-07-13 09:48:23.699 DEBUG 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
Hibernate: 
    select
        alpha0_.id as id1_0_,
        alpha0_.name as name2_0_ 
    from
        alpha alpha0_ 
    where
        alpha0_.id in (
            ?
        )
2018-07-13 09:48:23.699 TRACE 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [a2]
2018-07-13 09:48:23.721 DEBUG 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] org.hibernate.SQL                        : 
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        relationship 
    where
        from_id=? 
        and to_id=?
2018-07-13 09:48:23.722 TRACE 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [a1]
2018-07-13 09:48:23.724 TRACE 7964 --- [nio-9000-exec-5] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [a2]
```

The key piece being `delete from relationship where from_id=? and to_id=?`

Now the problem arises when trying to delete the second `Alpha` relationship `A3`, in which Hibernate does almost the exact same sequence, except for the `DELETE` query which omits the `and to_id=?` from the query, i.e.

```
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        relationship 
    where
        from_id=?
```

Which has the unintended consequence of deleting all other `A1` relationships in the table, i.e. `B1` and `B2`.

So that is the crux of my problem. It seems like Hibernate is only seeing one other related `Alpha` record and therefore deciding to simplify the query by omitting the `and to_id` statement.

I'm probably missing something terribly obvious!

I should also point out that I attempted to use a composite key on the `relationship` table but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an unusual design, which I suspect is confusing `Hibernate`.  Sharing a single join table between multiple `Many-to-many` relationships, isn't good database design, for one it can't have any foreign keys/referential integrity.

Secondly, `Hibernate` manages relationships, and therefore has control over the `@JoinTable`, I don't know how it would handle multiple entity relationships mapped with the same table.  Evidently, not very well though!

The simplest solution (if you're able to), would be to have 2 mapping tables.  One for the relationship between `Alpha-Alpha` and another between `Alpha-Bravo`.

Comment: And to avoid mapping the relationship table as an entity since it's already mapped as a join table.

Comment: I completely agree.  Mapping relationships to entities is usually followed by code that micro-manages the relationship outside of `Hibernate`.

Comment: @StuPointerException I completely agree with you, the whole database design is a mess, and in my opinion, needs to be scrapped post haste! Unfortunately, it's what I'm stuck with for now. I thought perhaps my lack of experience with JPA/Hibernate was the issue, but if the consensus is that this can't be done properly, then I'll have my answer.

Comment: @jdub I feel your pain.  I can't see anything wrong with your `Hibernate` annotations.  If it's any consolation, I don't think splitting the join table into 2 should be a very big/risky task.  That being said, it may not be the last hurdle to overcome if the rest of the database follows similar "patterns".  Good luck!